# There is no argument give that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'form1.Form1(string[])

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make my program startup when you right click an image file and then select "add flagto game" so i did this:

```
public Form1(string[] args)
{
InitializeComponent();
imageloc = args[0];
}
```

but then i get the error that is in the title! there is a similar question but that didn't have the answer so i am asking it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just change the constructor of your form, you also need to change the code that calls it.

Assuming you're using winforms, your `Program.cs` file should look like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Change it to:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1(args));
}
```

More specifically, I changed two things:

- I added the `string[] args` parameter to the signature of the `Main` function. That's what you tried to do with the constructor of your form
- I updated the call to `new Form1` to give the args parameter: `new Form1(args)`

Comment: thank you! i forgot to change the Main in program.cs